# Installing packages using PIP, then using that package on a system with multiple versions of Python installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to use the package [md-to-html](https://pypi.org/project/md-to-html/). The instructions to install:

```
pip install md-to-html
```

I'm on "Debian Rodete." I did `pip` and got `command not found.` I was unsure the best way to install `pip`, because if I do `python [TAB]`, I see:

```
python             python3            python3.6          python3.6m-config  python3m-config
python2            python3.5          python3.6-config   python3-config     
python2.7          python3.5m         python3.6m         python3m
```

So, I did `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`.

Then, `pip3 --version` returning `pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)` confirmed it was installed.

Then, I tried `pip3 install md-to-html`. I got `Successfully installed md-to-html-0.3.0`.

Then, I tried `python3 -m md-to-html`. I got `/usr/bin/python3: No module named md-to-html`.

Because pip version indicated something about python 3.6, I tried `python3.6 -m md-to-html`. I got `/usr/bin/python3.6: No module named md-to-html`.

I read online that the best way to use pip now is `python3 -m pip`. So, I tried `python3 -m pip install md-to-html`. I got `Successfully installed md-to-html-0.3.0`.

Then, I tried `python3 -m md-to-html`, and I got `/usr/bin/python3: No module named md-to-html`.

So, I tried `python3 -m pip list`. `md-to-html (0.3.0)` is within the list.

**What's the proper way to install pip packages and then use those packages on a system with multiple versions of Python installed?**

Comment: `virtualenv` is your friend in this situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a virtual environment for one of the python versions, and then use its pip to install the package. That way you can explicitly choose that environment when working on your project (and don't need to remember which python version installed what).

To install:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

To choose the python version

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 venv
```

or

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.5 venv
```

Using a virtual environment is as simple as having a `venv` folder in your workspace that you "turn on" when you want to work on that project:

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $
```

Packages installed with pip are stored in the `venv` folder.

To deactivate:

```
(venv) $ deactivate
$
```

If you mess up, you can always delete the `venv` folder and restart the process.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth answer. I tried `pip3 install virtualenv`, then based on the virtualenv docs, did `python3 -m virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 venv`. Output didn't indicate errors. Then I tried `python3 -m pip install mdn-to-html`, and got the error `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mdn-to-html (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mdn-to-html`

Comment: md**n**-to-html (maybe a typo)

Comment: I didn't realize I no longer need python3.6 -m now, I can now use scripts directly via `md-to-html` for example. Let me ensure this works and if so I'll mark as correct.

Comment: The md-to-html package has all sorts of issues, but this seems to be the correct answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `pip install something`, you can do `python -m pip install something`. That way, you get to choose into which python installation you are installing. In your case, e.g.

```
python3.6 -m pip install md-to-html
```

or

```
python3.5 -m pip install md-to-html
```

or whatever other version.

Comment: I tried this, and after following your first step, tried `python3.6 -m md-to-html` and got `no module named md-to-html`

Comment: I don't know anything about `md-to-html`, but a module cannot be named `md-to-html`. That is not a valid Python identifier. Just because that is the pip package name, does not mean you can import it with `python -m`.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a system you're stuck with and someone else makes decisions for?  like an it department? If not check out venv.

I just wanted to make sure this isn't a situation that could benefit from using virtual environments. Here's the link just incase.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

On 3.5+ the recommended way to make a venvs is

`pthon -m venv yourVenvName`

That link goes over how to create them in 3.5+ and touches on virtual environments in past versions. You can find what you need from there easily :)

Comment: Hmm, you rlink didn't work, but I found it here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html